# If $f$ is lower semi-continuous, then $g(x)=1/f(x)$ is upper semi-continuous

Tags: general-topology

> Let $f: M\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be lower semi-continuous, such that $f(x)>0$ for every $x\in M$. Prove that $g:M \rightarrow M$, $g(x) = \dfrac{1}{f(x)}$, is upper semi-continuous.

I must show that $\dfrac{1}{f(x)}<\dfrac{1}{f(a)} + \epsilon $, but i can't really find a manipulation to get on this by using the fact that $f(a)-r<f(x)$ for every $r>0$. Maybe i have to get an $r$ related to $\epsilon$, but i don't know how to proceed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint/suggestion: use the Taylor explansion of $1/(1-x)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\tag{1}\frac1{f(x)}<\frac1{f(a)}+\varepsilon\iff f(x)>\frac1{\frac1{f(a)}+\varepsilon}=\frac{f(a)}{1+\varepsilon f(a)}.$$Since $f$ is lower semi-continuous and $\frac{f(a)}{1+\varepsilon f(a)}<f(a)$, there is a $\delta>0$ such that, when $|x-a|<\delta$, $(1)$ holds.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\varepsilon > 0$. By lower semi-continuity of $f$ at $a \in \mathbb{R}$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $$|x-a|<\delta \implies f(a) - \frac{\varepsilon f(a)^2}{1+\varepsilon f(a)} < f(x)$$

For $x\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $|x-a|<\delta$ we have:

$$\frac{1}{f(x)} < \frac{1}{f(a) - \frac{\varepsilon f(a)^2}{1+\varepsilon f(a)}} = \frac{1 + \varepsilon f(a)}{f(a) + \varepsilon f(a)^2 - \varepsilon f(a)^2} = \frac{1}{f(a)} + \varepsilon$$

Thus, $f$ is upper semi-continuous at $a$.